# How to assign "Vue Js" tags in globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I'm New to Vue.js, here i having trouble to declare the delimiter in all instances.

**My CODE :**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <p>${ message }</p>
</div>

<div id="app-2">
   <span v-bind:title="message">
      Hello ${ message }
   </span>
</div>
```

**Vue.JS :**

```
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    data: {
        message: 'Hi all !'
    }
});

var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    data: {
        message: 'you will load in ' + new Date()
    }
});
```

Is there any way to declare the tags "**delimiters: ['${', '}']**" in globally to common for all Vue instance inside the page ?

Comment: See if [Mixin](https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the following line makes the thing you want:

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['<%', '%>']

new Vue({

})
```

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using?

Comment: it's Vue Js 2.0

Comment: Ho, I see, I am sorry, this has been deprecated in 2.0: http://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#Vue-config-delimiters-deprecated so you will have to use what you are already using. Or using Mixins like @Mathew Jibin suggested